# Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, aar

Added another version of `AAR` to the libs directory, after click `Sync` an error appeared

> Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=mylib-release-1.13.aar, variantName=null, artifactFile=D:...\app\libs\mylib-release-1.13.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={current_build=D:...}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@60eddcd6)

Even after I changed the version of the library to 1.14 and did `Sync`, the problem remained. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Sure your `app` module `build.gradle` must have `libs` not `lib`

```
implementation files('libs/mylib-release-1.13.aar')
```

Comment: I've had similar issue where another module was using this dependency in it's build.gradle .. See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74107043/3192693

Answer (score 1):

That error is because gradle does not find the .aar, check if you are in the right project, generally it is app. And then add the implementation, for me it worked using this in the gradle app module

```
implementation files('libs/player-release.aar')
```

And the .aar was located in: *C:\Users\denis\workspace\PlayerApp\app\sdk\libs*