# Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact on gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, gitlab

i cloned a project from gitlab and when trying to build it i get the following error:

Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=printerlib-release.aar, variantName=null, artifactFile=C:\Users\RayanSystem\Desktop\New folder (2)\printerlib-release.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={**current_build**=D:\Workspace\hozorghiab-newTablet}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@78144c8c)

i then got the required file from the previous developer and added it to my src/libs folder but it still didn't work

things i've tried:

1. increasing memory in gradle.properties -> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
2. adding the following to the gradle file
   implementation files("libs/printerlib-release.aar")
   implementation files("libs/PrinterSdk-release.aar")
   along side with the implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
   but it was no help at all

if anyone knows the trick i would very appreciate the help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error Null extracted folder for artifact, after I replaced the library with an updated library.

for eg. Previous library was **my_lib_1.24.aar** .. And after replacing it with **my_lib_1.25.aar**, the build was failing with this error.

I've already added implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar', '.aar']) in app gradle.

Turns out, another module was explicitly depending on **my_lib_1.24.aar**, from the app module. So by renaming this to **my_lib_1.25.aar** the error is gone and build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

clean your project first `gradlew clean` then re-sync `gradlew assembleDebug`
or after clean project then invalidate cache android studio/intellij idea to clean sync

Answer (score 0):

your path should be like that;

```
implementation files("../app/libs/libraryName.aar")
```